# How to dispaly the Oracle search results?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am practicing some examples in Oracle as i am new to it. I want to display the rows that are matched to First WHERE clause at beginning and last matched WHERE clause rows at last of below table.

```
  CREATE table demo(id int, name varchar(50), city varchar(20), zip varchar(20));
    insert into demo values(1,'oliver71','munich','85716');

    insert into demo values(2,'markus71','munich','85716');
    insert into demo values(3,'oliver81','stuttgart','70024');
    insert into demo values(4,'peter82','hale','81978');
    insert into demo values(5,'chinnarose71','rosenheim','80324');
    insert into demo values(6,'guru11','berlin','81982');
    insert into demo values(7,'sachin51','frankfurt','00712');

    select name, city, zip from demo where zip like '%7%' OR city LIKE '%7%' 
     OR name LIKE '%7%';
```

How can i do that in Oracle. Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no "WHEN" clause in your query.  I assume you mean the parts of the WHERE clause.

To do this, you need a way of ordering the results.  Here is one way using a subquery, which I think might be the clearest:

```
select name, city, zip
from (select name, city, zip,
             (case when zip like '%7%' then 1
                   when city LIKE '%7%' then 2
                   when name LIKE '%7%' then 3
                   else 0
              end) as matchitem
      from demo
     ) d
where matchitem > 0
order by matchitem
```